# How can you solve the mini_racer 0.2.4 compilation issue to solve a Bundler dependency on Fedora 31?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rubygems, v8

Landing on an existing Rails project, I encounter some difficulty with setting up the environment, which makes pop up the infamous "dependency hell" in my head. It seems limited to mini_racer 0.2.4 though.

Here is how it goes:

```
bundle install
# […] lot of working stuffs
Fetching libv8 6.7.288.46.1 (x86_64-linux)
Installing libv8 6.7.288.46.1 (x86_64-linux)
# […] more working stuffs
Fetching mini_racer 0.2.4
Installing mini_racer 0.2.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


    current directory: /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension
/home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby -I /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20200404-68221-1tr6jr3.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension
make "DESTDIR="
compiling mini_racer_extension.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-int' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
mini_racer_extension.cc: In function 'void prepare_result(v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, v8::TryCatch&, v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Context>, EvalResult&)':
mini_racer_extension.cc:234:73: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Value::ToObject()'
  234 |                         String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "JSON"))->ToObject();
      |                                                                         ^
In file included from mini_racer_extension.cc:4:
/home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include/v8.h:2390:44: note: candidate: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>
v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
 2390 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
[…]
[A lot of other compiling errors]
[…]
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-constant-logical-operand'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-parentheses-equality'
make: *** [Makefile:210: mini_racer_extension.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/mini_racer-0.2.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.2.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mini_racer -v '0.2.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer
```

Browsing the web, one can easily find [mini-racer failing to compile · Issue #4 · jules2689/extended_bundler-errors](https://github.com/jules2689/extended_bundler-errors/issues/4) leading to [Add mini_racer handling](https://github.com/jules2689/extended_bundler-errors/commit/d0eb62c8a381e293878a337901dba64238f65e64). From this I tried `gem uninstall libv8 && gem install mini_racer -v '0.2.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/` but it fails to compile just as above.

Now, running `bundle update && bundle install` works like a charm, so I thought I might just go with this for now and see with the rest of the team if we might update at least the mini-racer gem. Then I started to complete the README.md to add some details and wanted to commit in a new branch and ask review. But it happens that the team use overcommit to add some git hooks which are crashing as it includes Brakeman which depends on mini_racer-0.2.4:

```
git commit -m"Add more detailed procedure on how to install on Fedora 31"
Running pre-commit hooks
Analyze with RailsBestPractices..................[RailsBestPractices] OK
Check for vulnerable versions of gems...................[BundleAudit] WARNING
Run Brakeman...............................................[Brakeman] FAILED
/home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find mini_racer-0.2.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

Run YarnLint...............................................[YarnLint] OK

✗ One or more pre-commit hooks failed
```

Summary of the development platform:

- Fedora 31 with an out of the box GCC 9.3.1 20200317 (Red Hat 9.3.1-1)
- RVM 1.29.10
- Bundler version 1.17.3
- Ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 5.2.2
- PATH: /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@the_project/bin:/home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/psychoslave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/psychoslave/.local/bin:/home/psychoslave/.local/bin:/home/psychoslave/bin:/home/psychoslave/.local/bin:/home/psychoslave/.config/nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin:/home/psychoslave/.local/bin:/home/psychoslave/.local/bin:/home/psychoslave/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/psychoslave/.rvm/bin
- LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH are empty

What steps would you recommand to solve this depency issue?

Comment: Brakeman doesn't depend on mini_racer, even transitively...

Answer (score 1):

For what it worths, our team simply runned `bundle update mini_racer`, and everything works now. Of course, it still doesn't make mini_racer 0.2.4 compiles on Fedora 31.